# errors during render vue-chart js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I am trying render Pie chart via vue-chartjs library.
But I have several mistakes, and I can't understand, how to solve it..

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="page-title">
      <h3>История записей</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="history-chart">
      <canvas ref="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <Loader v-if="loading" />
    <p class="center" v-else-if="!records.length">Записей пока нет. <router-link to="/record"> Добавьте первую
      </router-link>
    </p>
    <section v-else>
      <HistoryTable :records="items" />
      <Paginate v-model="page" :page-count="pageCount" :click-handler="pageChangeHandler" :prev-text="'Назад'"
        :next-text="'Вперед'" :container-class="'pagination'" :page-class="'waves-effect'" />
    </section>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import paginationMixin from '@/mixins/pagination.mixin';
import HistoryTable from '@/components/HistoryTable.vue';
import Loader from '@/components/app/Loader.vue';
import { Pie } from 'vue-chartjs'


export default {
  name: 'history',
  extends: Pie,
  mixins: [paginationMixin],
  data: () => ({
    loading: true,
    records: [],
  }),
  components: {
    HistoryTable,
    Loader
  },

  async mounted() {
    this.records = await this.$store.dispatch("fetchRecords");
    const categories = await this.$store.dispatch("fetchCategories");

    this.setup(categories)

    this.loading = false
  },

  methods: {
    setup(categories) {

      this.setupPagination(this.records.map(record => {
        return {
          ...record,
          categoryName: categories.find(c => c.id === record.categoryId).title,
          typeClass: record.type === 'income' ? 'green' : 'red',
          typeText: record.type === 'income' ? 'Доход' : 'Расход',
        }
      }))

      this.renderChart({
        labels: categories.map(c => c.title),
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Расходы по категориям',
            data: categories.map(c => {
              return this.records.reduce((total, r) => {
                if (r.categoryId === c.id && r.type === 'outcome') {
                  total += +r.amount
                }
                return total
              }, 0)
            }),
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
      })
    },
  },
}

</script>
```

These errors appears when start project..

[image]

What kind of 'chartData' console want?
Why this.renderChart is not a function? I wrote that this is a function in methods.
What kind of 'in' operator I uses?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
If downgrade version from v4 -> v3 for vuechartjs and chart js from v3 -> v2 all be all right.